# Network user usage alerting options?

Tags: proxy, squid, bandwidth

My company is offering public wireless in a number of locations. Access is controlled by an OpenBSD box running pf and Squid in transparent proxy mode. Using a tool like SARG, I can easily generate an HTML report that shows IP addresses and amount of data transferred. However, utilizing the data requires a human to look at the generated log and see if there is a problem.

I was wondering if there was any tool I could use to send us an alert if a single user exceeded a certain threshold of data transfer? Something that would analyze the log like SARG, but rather than generating a report simply send an e-mail if any "problems" are detected.

Edit 1-as squid is set up as a transparent proxy, there are no "users" per-se. Rather, it logs IP's which I can match up to MAC addresses using the DHCP logs. I'm just looking for something that can send me an e-mail if a given IP transfers more than x amount of data in a given time period.

Comment: Does this setup actually identify users via an authentication mechanism? If not, it would be very hard to differentiate between a user and any other generic client. Especially if the IP addresses get re-used over time.

Comment: It gives the IP addresses of the clients, which I can match up to mac address using the DHCP logs. I make no distinction between different devices connecting. The idea being that if I see a pattern of high usage from a given client, I want to know about it.

Comment: I wish I could be of more direct help, but either a squid modification/plugin or log analyzer is likely to be the best solution if I had to guess, I hope this helps!

Comment: I have built systems that do this using flow-tools for the data management.  I will be interested to see if you are able to get any answers tha include actual tools that do this (and are open source).

Answer (score 1):

Periodic use of `pfctl -s state -v` and some use of AWK would work.

The above command also includes the session age.

You'd have to poll fairly regularly and make use of a cronjob or similar and do some scripting magic to aggregate IP addresses, but it would work.

Rob